# Undefined behaviour of Designated initializers in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer

The following C++20 program is accepted without any warning in all compiles I have tried:

```
struct A { const int & x = z; int y = x; int z; };

int main()
{
    return A{.z=3}.y;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nqb95zb7c

But every program returns some arbitrary value. Is it right to assume that this is undefined behavior?

Comment: `y = x`, so `y = z` reads `z` before it is initialized.

Comment: GCC points out @Jarod42 comment and clang bails with no code - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3fxKhrKnb

Comment: You can also use constant evaluation to catch undefined behaviour: https://godbolt.org/z/WYv1W8PcW (which makes gcc point out the uninitialised access)

Comment: *it right to assume that this is undefined behavior?*  Yes, because reading an uninitialized variable is **undefined behavior**.  Could be an arbitrary value, could crash, could awaken Cthulhu from his slumber, or worse... could appear to work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Members are initialized in the order they appear in the class definition, hence the designated initializer is not that relevant, and also this

```
struct A { 
    const int & x = z; 
    int y = x;           // <- read of indeterminate value !
    int z = 42;          // <- doesn't really matter because y is initialized before ! 
};

int main() {
    return A{}.y;
}
```

is undefined for the same reason.

---

See also the example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> ```
> struct A {
>   string str;
>   int n = 42;
>   int m = -1;
> };
> A{.m=21}  // Initializes str with {}, which calls the default constructor
>           // then initializes n with = 42
>           // then initializes m with = 21
> ```

The example is actually to illustrate something else, but it also shows how members are initialized in order.